# assert when X is true Y is true too - implication

Tags: c++

How to assert that if `X` is `true` then `Y`is `true` as well. The problem is that if I write the following:

```
assert(X && Y && "If X is true then Y should be true too.");
```

will fail, if `bool X = false;` whereas this can be a valid case too.

Comment: `!X || Y` should do the job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logical expression is: `assert(!X || (X && Y))`

If you want your message included, you can just wrap it in parentheses:

```
assert((!X || (X && Y)) && "If X is true then Y should be true too.");
```

Now, we can simplify this logic, because we know that if `!X` evaluated to `false` (and we're evaluating the right side of `||`), then we know that `X` must be true, so we can further simplify it:

```
assert(!X || Y); // If !X is false, then X must be true, so no need to test it.
```

Comment: Another way to think about the simplification is that if `Y` is true then it doesn't matter whether or not `X` is true. Likewise, if `X` is not true, then it doesn't matter whether or not `Y` is true.

Answer (score 2):

```
constexpr bool a_implies_b( bool a, bool b ) {
  return a?b:true;
}
```

then:

```
assert(a_implies_b(X, Y) && "If X is true then Y should be true too.");
```

or, if you want to have fun...

```
namespace implies_trick {
  struct lhs_t {
    bool v;
    constexpr lhs_t(bool b):v(b) {}
  };
  struct implies_t { constexpr implies_t() {} };
  constexpr implies_t implies = {};
  constexpr lhs_t operator->*( bool a, implies_t ) { return {a}; }
  constexpr bool operator*( lhs_t a, bool b ) { return a.v?b:true; }
}
using implies_trick::implies;

for (bool X:{true, false})
  for (bool Y:{true, false})
    std::cout << X << "->" << Y << " is " << X ->*implies* Y << "\n";
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64953663a20c4d61).

which lets you write:

```
assert(X ->*implies* Y && "If X is true then Y should be true too.");
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to assert that if X is true then Yis true as well

What you're describing is [implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional): `X → Y`

There isn't an implication operator in C++. But it's trivial to prove for example using a truth table that that `X → Y` is equivalent to `¬X ∨ Y`. That we can write in C++, because it has both negation and OR-operator (disjunction):

```
assert(!X || Y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Yakk's nice answer but with a different syntax:

```
#include <iostream>


namespace detail {

    struct when_impl
    {
        constexpr when_impl(bool condition)
        : _cond(condition)
        {}

        constexpr operator bool() const { return _cond; }
        bool _cond;
    };

    struct then_impl
    {
        constexpr then_impl(bool condition)
        : _cond(condition)
        {}

        constexpr operator bool() const { return _cond; }
        bool _cond;
    };

}

constexpr auto when(bool condition)
{
    return detail::when_impl(condition);
}

constexpr auto then(bool condition)
{
    return detail::then_impl(condition);
}

constexpr bool operator,(detail::when_impl when, detail::then_impl then)
{
    if (bool(when)) return bool(then);
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    for (bool X:{true, false})
        for (bool Y:{true, false})
            std::cout << X << "->" << Y << " is " << (when(X), then(Y)) << "\n";

    static_assert((when(true), then(true)), "Y must follow X");
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
1->1 is 1
1->0 is 0
0->1 is 1
0->0 is 1
```

(note: static_assert does not fire during build)

Comment: That's a lot of effort to define a new syntax that's difficult to understand.